# Regex to check if a character occurs more than X times in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What is the regex to check if a character occurs more than 2 times in a string? Example: "aab" is allowed, but not "aaa" or "aaba".

Is there a way to make it match only on valid inputs (when there are less than 3 repeating characters) so that the preg_match() function returns 1 for valid input (with less than 3 repeating characters) and else 0?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `substr_count($str, "a")` instead of regex.

Comment: So if the string is `aabaabaa` is that allowed because the repeat is never more then 2?

Comment: Specified now. The "aabaabaa" should not be accepted.

Comment: @liberty So is it just the same character more then three times in a string?

Answer (score 1):

This regex would find a character that repeats 3 times (or more because have to hit the three to get more).

```
(.)\1{2}
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/WmUPWW/1

PHP Usage:

```
foreach(array('aaa', 'aab') as $string) {
    if(preg_match('/(.)\1{2}/', $string)) {
         echo $string . ' doesnt match :(' . "\n";
    } else {
         echo $string . ' matches'. "\n";
    }
}
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/672382

Comment: Gotta love demos. The proof's in the pudding, as it were ;-)

Comment: Is there a way to make preg_match return 1 if it exists? Just asking because I want to loop through several expressions.

Comment: @liberty that is what it does, that is why it enters the conditional. https://eval.in/672387 Per the manual: `preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.`. or a demo storing the return in a variable, https://eval.in/672389.

Comment: If this works for you please remember to accept the answer.

Comment: @chris85 Sorry, I meant 1 if the pattern does not exist and 0 if it exists.

Comment: You could use the ternary operator to do the inverse, `$var = preg_match('/(.)\1{2}/', $string) ? 0 : 1;`. https://eval.in/672399 or just `!preg_match`.

Comment: @chris85 sure I can, but I want to loop through several regular expressions, and some of them should match and others should not match. Is there any way to make it inverse in the expression itself?

Comment: The above regex demo doesn't seem to work any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex match and a not in the condition

In the following x is max_length+1

```
(?:[^<letter>]*<letter>[^letter]*){x}
```

For letter b for example you'd use

```
(?:[^b]*b[^b]*){x}
```

For all vowels

```
 (?:[^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*){x}
```

For regex usage on php refer to https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_regex.asp

Comment: 1) `{0-2}` is a syntax error. 2) `(?:.*b.*){0,2}` matches `bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`.

Comment: @Toto you are right and is also missing a not match, I also added some optimizations I found upon testing